# Angular directive test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular.js, jasmine

I'm learning how to write tests in Angular (these are my first tests in general). There are a lot of tutorials out there but each one of them has a different approach. I'm a bit confused if I'm doing things the right way.

I made a simple directive for testing purposes and I've called it tooltip (though its not really a tooltip).

**tooltip.js**:

```
angular.module('mytestapp', []);

(function(){
    angular.module('mytestapp').directive('tooltip', tooltip);

    function tooltip() {
        var directive = {
            controller: tooltipCtl,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            restrict: 'E',
            template:
                "<span>This is a tooltip for {{ name }}</span>" +
                "<button ng-click='vm.myFun()'>Click me!</button>",
            scope: {
                name: '@'
            },
            link: link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, elem, attrs) {}
    }

    function tooltipCtl() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.things = 3;

        vm.myFun = myFun;
        function myFun() {
          vm.age = 30;
        }
    }

})();
```

**tooltip.spec.js**:

```
describe('tooltip', function () {
    angular.mock.module('mytestapp');
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mytestapp'));

    describe('template', function () {
        var $compile;
        var $scope;
        var element;
        var controller;
        // beforeEach(module('templates'));

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            element = angular.element("<tooltip name='john'></tooltip>");
            element = $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        }));

        beforeEach(function () {
            controller = element.controller('tooltip');
        });

        it('should have name equal to john', function (){
            expect(element.html()).toContain('john');
        });

        it('should have 3 items', function (){
            expect(controller.things).toBe(3);
        });

        it('should set age when clicked to 30', function () {
            expect(controller.myFun).toBeDefined();
            controller.myFun();
            expect(controller.age).toBe(30);
        });

    });
});
```

I'm using Karma and Jasmine, Angular 1.4.7, angular-mocks and ng-html2js. I'd be thankful for a general review of my code. Links to some good, up-to-date guides would help as well.

Additional questions:

1. I have ng-html2js included but I didn't really use it, can I use it in my example? Should I do it? Yes/no, and why?
2. I have a `beforeEach(module('templates'));` that I've used in some previous example but my spec works without it here. Is this module-templates things something common, or is there some sort of pattern where you use it?
3. I've used `angular.mock.module` but my spec works fine with just `module`. Any tips here?

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't really need to use ng-html2js since you don't really have a file `.html` file.
2. Answered on question 1.
3. You can just use `angular.mock.module` if you want. I usually use this pattern for my tests.

Example:

```
const angular = window.angular,
  expect = window.chai.expect,
  sinon = window.sinon;

const inject = angular.mock.inject,
  module = angular.mock.module;
```

I have a repo with some patterns for unit testing. Feel feel to take a look at it.

https://github.com/rodoabad/angularjs-unit-testing-patterns